# Specialization Name

Tags: halo-4

In multiplayer, when you reach SR-130, can you change the specialization name displayed below your Spartan? For example, if you choose Stalker as your last specialization, will it be set to "Stalker" forever or can you freely switch it to another specialization name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some of the more recent patches (CSR patch I think) it will now display `Mastery` as the specialization for anyone who has finished all specializations and hit the SR-130 rank

Answer (score 2):

As of February 26th, at the latest, the space where specialization names appear is blank when you reach SR-130.  I noticed this while playing last night.

According to [this](http://www.examiner.com/article/first-halo-4-player-maxes-out-level-cap-at-130?cid=PROD-redesign-right-next) article, you can't:

> After reaching the maximum SR level in Halo 4, Deuce does have a couple of suggestions. For starters, let whatever Specialization title you want to be the the last one you play before reaching the cap. He discovered that you cannot change your title once you've reach the cap and he is now stuck as a Pathfinder.

This article was posted back in November, so perhaps it's been updated since then.  If anyone is SR-130 and can provide evidence proving otherwise I will accept that answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've heard in the community it is not possible to change the name once you hit SR130. What you choose as your last specialization is what shows up on your playercard. So yes it will say "Stalker" forever unless they release a patch that changes that, but from my knowledge there hasn't been any patch, and I've heard this from people that know others that are SR130 and were complaining about that feature.